# How to join tables with non-equal condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I’m trying to query all the users with their first successful app install with the app version details.

So I tried to query users’ first successful install, then compare the installed_date with latest app version before installed_date.

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, installed_time
WHERE state=SUCCESSFUL
FROM installation
ORDER BY ASC
```

The query above returns all users with their first successful installed.

How do I find which version of the app that they have installed when they first installed it successfully?

My tables are described below:

```
Installation:
user_id,
installed_date,

Version:
version_id,
release_date,
release_code,
```

Comment: Which database are you using? (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, ...)

Comment: @Andomar I’m using postgesql

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that this query does what you say:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, installed_time
WHERE state=SUCCESSFUL
FROM installation
ORDER BY ASC;
```

Apart from the obvious syntax errors, users with multiple installs will appear multiple times.  That may be what you want, but it is not the first successful install.

I think the query should be:

```
SELECT i.user_id, MIN(i.installed_time)
FROM installation i
WHERE i.state = 'SUCCESSFUL'
GROUP BY i.user_id;
```

Or, if you want all columns in the table, use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (i.user_id) i.*
FROM installation i
WHERE i.state = 'SUCCESSFUL'
ORDER BY i.user_id, i.installation_time
```

If you want the valid version at that time, you have several choices.  In Postgres, I would recommend a lateral join:

```
SELECT i.*, v.*
FROM (SELECT i.user_id, MIN(i.installed_time) as installed_time
      FROM installation i
      WHERE i.state = 'SUCCESSFUL'
      GROUP BY i.user_id
     ) i LEFT JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT v.*
      FROM versions v
      WHERE v.release_date <= i.installed_time
      ORDER BY v.release_date DESC
      FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
     ) v
     ON 1=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve it by using **window-functions**. Window functions are extremely useful for "advanced" SQL scrips.

As usual in software, there are many ways of doing this, this is a simple one using `FIRST_VALUE()`.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  i.user_id,
  FIRST_VALUE(v.version_id) OVER(
    PARTITION BY i.user_id
    ORDER BY v.released_date DESC
  ) AS first_version_installed
FROM installation AS i
INNER JOIN version AS v
  ON i.installation_date >= v.released_date
WHERE i.state = 'SUCCESSFULL'
```

Further reading:

- Window functions: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`distinct on (...)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) with an `order by` to get the version of the earliest installation.  The `distinct on` expression must match the leftmost `order by` expression.

```
select  distinct on (i.user_id)
,       i.user_id
,       i.installed_date 
,       v.release_code
from    installation i
join    version v
on      v.release_date <= i.installed_date
where   i.state = 'SUCCESSFUL'
order by
        i.user_id              -- Required for distinct on, see note above
,       i.installed_date desc  -- First installation per user
,       v.release_date         -- Latest version available at installation date
```